# On and In in different contexts

Tags: grammaticality

It's a little confusing why people use "in" before movies like "Jonny depp played a pirate in Pirates of the caribbean while they use on before series. Like, "Previously on Game of thrones".
Please help me here. Thank you.

Comment: They are not similar so we cannot expect similarity. An actor plays a part *in* a film. He is in the film like a cake is in the oven...inside it.  Thrones is on TV, not on top of the TV but the show is on now, occurring now, actively broadcasting or streaming at this time. Dinner is on.  Previously means this is what took place *on* the show when the show was on TV last time.

Comment: Welcome to English Language and Usage. Prepositions such as "in", "at", and "on" may be the most commonly used, but they can also be confusing. There are some basic rules for usage when used to describe location and dates, but in other cases it is just idiomatic, and there probably is no adequate way to explain the logic behind it that a non-native speaker could readily understand

Comment: @YosefBaskin "Thrones is on TV", true, but Ben Affleck played the role of Matt Murdock **in** Daredevil (the movie), whereas Charlie Cox plays the role of Matt Murdock **on** Daredevil (the Netflix show). "On TV" isn't really relevant to this discussion, as both the movie and the show can both be shown on TV. Even after the show finale of Daredevil, we will still say that  Charlie Cox played the role of Matt Murdock **on** Daredevil (the Netflix show), so it's also not a matter of "on" meaning "ongoing".

Comment: Yeah actually the logic of "on TV" doesn't really matter in this case. On TV.. on screen.. It sounds like it's entirely a different subject.

Comment: It is all usage. The common expressions are "IN the movies" and "ON television."
Because it is usage, there is no special way to explain it. And learning the usage in this case will not serve as a guide to the usage in a different case ("on the train" and "in the elevator," for example, or "on an airplane" and "in a canoe."